# What happens if I source a script as background process?

Tags: bash, shell, background, subshell

From the BASH pages:

> When a script is run using source **it runs within the existing shell**,
>   any variables created or modified by the script will remain available
>   after the script completes. In contrast if the script is run just as
>   filename, then a separate subshell (with a completely separate set of
>   variables) would be spawned to run the script.

But what happens if I run

```
. myscript &
```

Does it run as a subshell in this case? What's the difference between `. myscript &` and `./myscript &`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - you can easily test this:

Source file:

```
echo "Source File"
echo "Source PID - $BASHPID"
MYVAR=someval
```

Execute file:

```
. source 

echo "Exec PID -$BASHPID"
echo $MYVAR
echo done
```

Output:

```
Source File
Source PID - 34893
Exec PID - 34893
someval
done
```

If you use the `&` in the `. source` of the execute file, the execution order is different, and so are the PIDs associated with the process, and you can see the `MYVAR` variable set in the source file is not printed:

```
Exec PID - 34931

done
Source File
Source PID - 34932
```

Comment: So what should I do if I wanted to source a file in the background?  For my use case, I have a couple of slow processes in my `zshrc`, so I tried putting an `&` at the end of those slow lines.  Hoping that this would parallelize the shell startup.  It ended up helping a bunch, but I noticed none of the changes had any affect!  What is an effective way to make my `zshrc` startup asynchronous?

Comment: @arco444. Nice example. Changing the name of the `source` file (to `sourcefile` maybe ? ) might allow for faster comprehension! Seeing `.` immediately followed by `source` confused me for a minute!